# TikZ Confusion Matrix line break

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

I tried a TikZ example of a confusion matrix and I want to set a line break, but it does not work. How can I set a line break in the second and third node? When I try it with "\" I get some errors.

Can you help me out?

Thank you very much!

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum size=3cm,text width=1.5cm,align=left}]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=.1cm,column sep=.1cm] {
    \node (tpos) [box,
    label=left:\textbf{G},
    label=above:\textbf{G},
    ] {True \\ positive};
    &
    \node (fneg) [box,
    label=above:\textbf{Sentence with Line break!?},
    label=above right:\textbf{Summe},
    label=right:\( \mathrm{P}' \)] {False \\ negative};
    \\
    \node (fpos) [box,
    label=left:\textbf{Sentence with Line break!?},
    label=below left:\textbf{Summe},
    label=below:P] {False \\ positive};
    &
    \node (tneg) [box,
    label=right:\( \mathrm{N}' \),
    label=below:N] {True \\ negative};
    \\
};
 \node [rotate=90,left=.05cm of conmat,anchor=center,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{Ergebnis}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{Erwartungswert}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Seems, you want to have a linebreak in a 'label'. For that use `label={[align=left, font=\bfseries]left:{Sentence with \\ Line break!}}`        BTW: You should post runable minimal examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the text to be split in two, it is necessary that the line break `\\` not be included in the group \textbf{...}. It is sufficient here to write the sentence in two groups.

```
label=above:\textbf{Sentence with}\\ \textbf{Line break!?},
```

I have removed the bold writing from the second text and there is no problem.

```
 label={left:Sentence with\\ Line break!?},
```

I have set `align=center` as a global option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center,
box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum size=3cm,text width=1.5cm,align=left}]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=.1cm,column sep=.1cm] {
    \node (tpos) [box,
    label=left:\textbf{G},
    label=above:\textbf{G},
    ] {True \\ positive};
    &
    \node (fneg) [box,
    label=above:\textbf{Sentence with}\\ \textbf{Line break!?},
    label=above right:\textbf{Summe},
    label=right:\( \mathrm{P}' \)
    ] {False \\ negative};
    \\
    \node (fpos) [box,
    label={left:Sentence with\\ Line break!?},
    label=below left:\textbf{Summe},
    label=below:P
    ] {False \\ positive};
    &
    \node (tneg) [box,
    label=right:\( \mathrm{N}' \),
    label=below:N
    ] {True \\ negative};
    \\
};
 \node [rotate=90,left=.05cm of conmat,anchor=center,text width=1.5cm] {\textbf{Ergebnis}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{Erwartungswert}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screnshot]

Comment: The TikZ-Syntax is `font=\bfseries`

Comment: Here this syntax is not appropriate since not all texts should be written in bold.

Comment: @cis suggestion *is* appropriate.

Comment: @cis It is then necessary to use this option locally for it to work as marmot did. But it's also heavy. I prefer to use this option globally, as I did with `align=center`, the code is more readable for my taste.

Comment: @AndréC Thank you very much for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that cis made the point before me, so full credit to them. The font keys `font` and `node font` are made for precisely this. Instead of wrapping the text in `\textbf` you should use `font=\bfseries` and you are fine.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum size=3cm,text width=1.5cm,align=left}]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=.1cm,column sep=.1cm] {
    \node (tpos) [box,
    label=left:\textbf{G},
    label=above:\textbf{G},
    ] {True \\ positive};
    &
    \node (fneg) [box,
    label={[font=\bfseries,align=center]above:Sentence with\\ Line break!?},
    label=above right:\textbf{Summe},
    label=right:\( \mathrm{P}' \)] {False \\ negative};
    \\
    \node (fpos) [box,
    label={[font=\bfseries,align=center]left:Sentence with\\ Line break!?},
    label=below left:\textbf{Summe},
    label=below:P] {False \\ positive};
    &
    \node (tneg) [box,
    label=right:\( \mathrm{N}' \),
    label=below:N] {True \\ negative};
    \\
};
 \node [rotate=90,left=.05cm of conmat,anchor=center,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{Ergebnis}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{Erwartungswert}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]